# MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate not being called

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I realize this question has been inexactly asked around, but I haven't been able to find an answer to my problem.

I have a UITableViewController with static cells. One of these cells is meant to open a Mail Composer view, and dismiss it through the delegate after the user sends or cancels the email. My problem is that the delegate method is not being called. Here is my code:

```
class SideMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mailCVP.delegate = self
mailCVP = configureMailComposeVC()
            if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
                self.presentViewController(mailCVP, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else { //..// }
}

func configureMailComposeVC() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["momentosdetora@gmail.com"])
            mailComposerVC.setSubject("Contacto Momentos de Tora")

        return mailComposerVC
    }

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Can anybody spot anything I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: See other answers for a solution, but wanted to help anybody that had my specific problem. Basically I created a separate class to act as the delegate, but I failed to make sure that objects of that class didn't get released before the delegate call.

Answer (score 8):

`MFMailComposeViewController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController`, which already has a `delegate` property to handle navigation changes.

`MFMailComposeViewController` has another property called `mailComposeDelegate`, which is the property you are looking for.

Also, you should create the controller before setting the delegate.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you use

```
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self
```

Not this one

```
controller.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mailCVP.delegate = self
mailCVP = configureMailComposeVC()
```

This code sets the delegate but then creates a new instance, which doesn't have a delegate...

Note that there is also no point in creating the VC instance if `MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail` returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use

```
mailCVP.mailComposeDelegate = self
```

instead of

```
mailCVP.delegate = self
```

Moreover, in case of **Swift 3**, delegate method is somehow updated which is:

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?){
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```